# Make maze connected by removing internal walls

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, connected-components, disjoint-sets

Recently I've stumbled upon a strange graph problem. Here is a brief description.

> Given $n\times m$ matrix with $2n + 1$ rows such that each row contains $2m + 1$ characters "+", "-", "|", "."
>
> - First, last row, and first, last column are the borders of the maze.
> - Even coordinates, e.g. (0, 0), (0, 2), are filled with "+", which you can't step on.
> - Odd coordinates are filled with ".", which is used normally for the traversal.
> - The rest of the coordinates share "|", "-", "." characters. "|" defines a horizontal wall, whereas "-" defines vertical.

The problem asks to delete a minimal number of walls, i.e. "|" and "-", in order to make the whole maze connected.

The example is given below

### Input

```
2 3
+-+-+-+
|.|...|
+-+-+-+
|.|...|
+-+-+-+
```

### Output

```
2 3
+-+-+-+
|.....|
+.+-+-+
|.|...|
+-+-+-+
```

As you can see two walls are deleted, the vertical wall having the coordinate $(1, 2) $ and the horizontal wall with the coordinates $(2, 1)$.

This problem seems like a perfect application of Disjoint Set Union, but I am not convinced that this is any right approach to this problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use BFS/DFS to find the connected components and the walls separating them. If there are $C$ connected components, you need to remove $C-1$ walls, which form a spanning tree in the graph whose vertices are the components and whose edges correspond to walls.

Comment: Beautiful. You can post the solution and I can accept it. One small question though, how to detect the walls that need to be deleted?

Comment: You can use an MST algorithm, though probably there are better options.

Comment: @stackoverload Could you please mention the source URL of this problem?

Comment: @JohnL. unfortunately, I cannot give the source of the problem, as the description of the problem is not in English.

Comment: @stackoverload That is not a problem at all. People can read almost every language, nowadays, thanks to some tools.

Comment: @JohnL. no problem at all. Here is a link https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/12341/enter/. You need to register and check the last problem. I was translating this problem as well

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material in the question.   See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please don't put it in a comment -- [edit] the question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a graph traversal algorithm such as BFS/DFS to detect the connected components, and to construct a graph in which the vertices are connected components and the edges are walls adjacent to two connected components. A spanning tree in this graph corresponds to the walls that need to be removed.